# Sequalizejs adding paranoid configuration to an existing table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I created a table without the paranoid option, and i now want to change that table's definition to use paranoid.

I don't want to re-create the database since its already in production.
how can i do that using migrations?

should i use addColumn with deletedAt and just add the paranoid definition to the model, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I added the deletedAt field using migration like this:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // add altering commands here, calling 'done' when finished

      migration.addColumn(
          'mytablename',
          'deletedAt',
          {
              type: DataTypes.DATE,
              allowNull: true,
              validate: {
              }
          }
      );
    done();
  },

  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // add reverting commands here, calling 'done' when finished
    migration.removeColumn('mytablename', 'deletedAt');
    done();
  }
};
```

And added the configuration:

```
 paranoid: true,
```

to my model

It seems to work.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: I'd say that was is the preferred solution

Answer (score 6):

Small update.

According to the `sequelize` version `6.4.0`(what I am currently using), the migration looks like this:

```js
    module.exports = {
        up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.addColumn(
                'TABLE_NAME',
                'deletedAt',
                {
                    allowNull: true,
                    type: Sequelize.DATE
                })
        },
    
        down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.removeColumn('TABLE_NAME', 'deletedAt')
        }
    };
```

I mean that the `done` method is not required.

Comment: Notice that the down migration would "restore" all tables that have been deleted since the up migration was applied.

Comment: Also need to set ```paranoid: true``` in the model options parameter.